# Convert existing Shell Code to Python for files movement

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I am having below shell code that basically finds `*.jpg*` in the `source` directory that is having `multiple sub directories` and then `shuffle` it and `picks top 2100 files` to move to the `dest` directory in the similar folder that `source` has
Below is the command, Need help to convert the same into Pyhton.

```
cd source
find . -iname *.jpg | shuf | head -n 2100 | xargs -I{} mv {} ../dest/{}
```

Comment: How far have you gotten? For example, can you list all the jpg files and shuffle them?

Comment: yes..From Xargs need help

Comment: Start from `os.walk`: `os.walk('.')` will help you iterate all the subdirectories, returning lists of files for each subdirectory. Try `print(list(os.walk('.')))` to see how it works. Then go from that.

Answer (score 1):

you first need to walk the directory using `os.walk` - shuffling can be accomplished with `random.shuffle`. finally you can `shutil.move` to relocate the file to another location.

It would look something like this, though theres better implementations than keeping all this data in memory.

**NOTE:** This is recursive and will dig until the the last directory is reached.

```py
import os
import random
import shutil

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('directory/path'):
  random.shuffle(files)
  for filepath in [f for f in files if f.endswith('.jpg')][:2100]:
    shutil.move(os.path.join('dest', filepath))
```

Comment: This snippet won't do the same as the code in question. You should first concatenate all the `files` lists together, then shuffle and pick top 2100.

Comment: @afenster Ah! Thank you, I felt I was missing something. Fixed.

Comment: @Skarlett 'NonType' object is not Subscriptable  - Getting this error.. Anyway, I got the idea and will fix this

Comment: @RonyA Check the editted post, errors should be resolved (random.shuffle does not return a new data set, but instead modifies the one being acted on by pointer reference)